# PyQt5 does not redrawing widget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Force repainting does not repaint PyQt5 widget (Qlabel, QTextEdit, even QProgressBar and etc)

Tested platforms: Linux, MacOS

PyQt5 version: 5.15.7
Installed from pip

As example I created simple app that updating text in QLabel widget in `for` loop. Force repainting doesnt working

```py
import sys
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel)

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = QLabel('Test', self)
        self.text.move(10, 10)
        self.text.resize(60,20)

        self.button =  QPushButton('Run', self)
        self.button.move(17,40)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.some_activity)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 100, 80)
        self.show()

    def some_activity(self):
        for i in range(100):
            text = f'i = {i}'
            self.text.setText(text)
            # self.text.update() -> Nothing happens (it shouldnt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update)
            self.text.repaint() # -> Nothing happens
            self.repaint() # -> Nothing happens
            print(f'Text updated: {text}')
            sleep(0.03)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Video demonstration: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/766382334067867668/1047254684030742558/Screen_Recording_2022-11-29_at_11.54.05_PM.mov)

Comment: Don't use blocking functions such as `time.sleep()`, as they completely prevent the main thread to process its event queue (which means that it cannot receive paint events, which are those responsible of painting). If you want to call a function repeatedly, use QTimer.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for comment. I removed `time.sleep()` and extend `range()` to  `500000`, now it takes ~5s, but `.repaint()` function still doesnt repaint widget or screen. `some_activity` function should call once in program.

Comment: That won't change a lot because the for loop is still blocking the event loop. Why are you using the for loop in the first place? Do you need to wait for something happening (like a network reply)? Are you trying to do some sort of timeout?

Comment: @musicamante yes, i need wait network reply (For example fetching website using requests and bs4 then downloading files from urls on website. Thats why for loop in the first place). Sorry for long respond.

Comment: Then a for loop is *not* the correct way to do so. Requests should be put in a separate thread, specifically using QThread and signals since you need to interact with the UI. If you need to display some "waiting" text (ie. to show the elapsed time), then as said above use a QTimer.

Comment: @musicamante I put my function in QThread and connected thread signals to another function that updates the UI and now it works! Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to use `QThread` to use for loop in my program
Thanks [@musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) for helping.

```py
import sys
from time import sleep
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel)

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None): QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self): 
        for i in range(100):
            text = f'i = {i}'
            print(f'Text updated: {text}')
            self.signal.emit(text)
            sleep(.3)

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = QLabel('Test', self)
        self.text.move(10, 10)
        self.text.resize(60,20)

        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.signal.connect(self.signal, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

        self.button =  QPushButton('Run', self)
        self.button.move(17,40)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 100, 80)
        self.show()
    
    def signal(self, text): self.text.setText(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```